# not able to get the access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token

Why do I get the following error message?

```
{"error":{"message":"Error validating login secret. Since your application has a login secret in addition to a secret key, you must use the login secret and not the secret key with OAuth.","type":"OAuthException"}}

$url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$APPID.'&redirect_uri='.$RDURL.'&client_secret='.$APPSECRET.'&code='.$_GET['code'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the settings page of your application on Facebook, you have enabled this option:

> 'Forces use of login secret for OAuth call and for auth.login'

Try disabling it and see if it helps. If it doesn't though, try replacing the `$APPSECRET` with a 'login secret' if you have any.