# facebook oauth complaining of the missing "login secret"

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

this might seem like a repeat of a question that has been answered elsewhere, but I have ran into those answers and they're not helping...

so I keep getting this response (from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token) on my final part of the oauth login process (I've acquired the "code" received after approving the app via the facebook authorization dialog):
{"error":{"message":"Error validating login secret. Since your application has a login secret in addition to a secret key, you must use the login secret and not the secret key with OAuth.","type":"OAuthException"}}

other answers to this question are mentioning disabling the 'Forces use of login secret for OAuth call and for auth.login' option in the app settings. however that option is not in my settings (settings->advanced). the same issue is mentioned here [not able to get the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203096/not-able-to-get-the-access-token)

"login secret" as a concept is not being mentioned anywhere in the facebook api docs.

anyone have any ideas? I would really appreciate it...
thank you

addition:
Im not using any library but instead directly communicating with the FB api via python

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using old api, try downloading latest version form [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).

Now fb do not have secret key concept.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. however Im not using any library nor php to get things done. https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token is the access point thats returning the error msg

Comment: Perhaps you'll like to use [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-python-sdk)

Comment: the FB authorization work flow is pretty simple, and I want to avoid usage of any libraries... this login secret is the only thing standing in the way of getting an access token. Id like to solve it instead of using someone elses blackbox